# Why does the value of this static variable not change?

Tags: c++

obj.num has 2 different values but the value of y doesn't change. Does this have to do with initialization vs. assignment? It's something I can't quite wrap my head around.

```
class A {
public:
    int num;
    A(int num): num(num) {}
};

int get_number(int x) {
    A obj = A(x);
    static int y = obj.num;
    return y;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_number(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_number(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static local variables are defined once and only once for a function, when the function is first called. Once it's defined and initialized it will never be redefined or reinitialized.

To modify the value of any variable, `static` or not, one must *assign* to it.

Comment: What happens the second time y is "initialized"? Does the compiler just ignore the code?

Comment: @ps22222 That's right, it's already defined and initialized. It won't happen again no matter how many times you call the function. Otherwise it wouldn't be any difference from "normal" non-static local variables.

Comment: @ps22222, in other words, `static int y; y = obj.num;` would achieve the expected result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you - I was confused because I expected the compiler would throw some kind of error if there's an attempt to re-initialize the static variable.

Comment: @ps22222 No such luck on the error message. The ability to have thread-safe, one time initialization is too handy to go without. Lazy initialization of a single instance of an object, for example.